# will Omniture s.tl() function result in 0% bounce rate

Tags: adobe-analytics

Will the Omniture `s.tl()` function count as an additional 'visit', therefore resulting in a non-bounce for that visitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not count as an additional 'visit', however it will count as an additional 'hit'.

A visit consisting of more than one hit (in this circumstance, an `s.t()` and `s.tl()` call) are not counted as a *Bounce*. However, they are still counted as a *Single Access*.

Since Bounce Rate can legitimately be defined using either Single Access or Bounces, it's important to understand the differences between the two. Depending on whether you want the `s.tl()` call to include/exclude bounced visits would determine which method of bounce rate you'd want to use. [See this article](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/reference/index.html#Bounce_Rate) for 
everything you'd want to know about it and its various calculations.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that three has to be at least s.tl() between two s.t() for the visitor to not be a bounce?

Comment: If a visit has two hits, it's not a Bounce. Doesn't matter what type of hits they are. https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/analytics/components/metrics/bounces.html